# sequlize associations porblem

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

Let's say we have six tables (M,H,T,B,Y,P) and the relationships between them are as follows
M has many H, H belongs to M,
T has many H , H belongs to T
B has many H , H belongs to B
Y has many B , B belongs to Y
P has many T , T belongs to P
P has many Y , Y belongs to P

now the problem is to write a postgres sql query or using one of node Js ORM sequelize finders that finds all records from M by P.id.

i have found a solution by useing two query but there should be a solution using only one query

```
try{
            const result1 = await req.app.get('db')["M"].findAll({
                include :[{
                    model : req.app.get('db')["H"],
                    right : true ,
                    as : 'h',
                    where :{
                        t_id : {[Op.is]: null}
                    },
                    include:[{
                        model : req.app.get('db')["B"],
                        right : true ,
                        as : 'b',
                        include:[{
                            model : req.app.get('db')["Y"],
                            right : true ,
                            as : 'y',
                            include:[{
                                model : req.app.get('db')["P"],
                                right : true ,
                                as : 'p',
                                where :{
                                    id : id,
                                }
                            }]
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
            });
            const result2 = await req.app.get('db')["M"].findAll({
                include :[{
                    model : req.app.get('db')["H"],
                    right : true ,
                    as : 'h',
                    where :{
                        t_id : {[Op.not]: null}
                    },
                    include:[{
                        model : req.app.get('db')["T"],
                        right : true ,
                        as : 't',
                        include:[{
                           model : req.app.get('db')["P"],
                           right : true ,
                           as : 'p',
                           where :{
                               id : id,
                           }
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
            });
            result = [...result1,...result2]
        }
```